# How to get an old iCloud password reset?

Tags: iphone

My kids locked my old account by putting in the wrong password too many times. I can't remember my security questions and I don't remember my recovery account email address.
How can I reset my password and change it all over to my new account?

Comment: Your going to have to call them or put in a support ticket (they call you). This happened to me. They are very helpful

Answer (score 1):

When you have two-step vertification enabled, apple could not reset your password. You will need to use the recovery code aplle provided.

Is two-step vertification is **not** enabled, you could call applecare. They can reset the password for you.

For a list with all applecare numbers you can visit [this link](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232)